# ampersand not passing in a string variable via url

Tags: php, javascript, url

I am trying to pass a big url as a string to another php page and fetch it there via `$_REQUEST[]`
but it's not working.
Here is the code (JavaScript) from first page:

```
var url="index.php?module=Contacts&return_module=Campaigns&action=UD_DetailView&popuptype=detailview&select=enable&form=EditView&form_submit=false";
var intermediate_url="choose_template.php?variable_url="+url;

window.location=intermediate_url;
```

The code on other page is:

`<?php 
echo "url = ".$_REQUEST['variable_url'];
?>`

The echo I get on page choose_template.php is this :

```
url = index.php?module=Contacts
```

I don't understand. Why does it break at the occurance of first `&` ?
What should I do to bypass it ?

Comment: Think twice: Can you put a URL into a URL literally by concatenating them? Also please search before asking.

Comment: @hakra Whats the Problem in putting a URL as  a string variable in another url ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using in js:

```
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Than in php:

```
echo "url = ". urldecode($_REQUEST['variable_url']);
```

Answer (score 2):

When manipulating url, you should use urlencode and urldecode functions

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
```

In javascript:

```
url = encodeURIComponent(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using urlencode():

```
var url="<?php echo urlencode('index.php?module=Contacts&return_module=Campaigns&action=UD_DetailView&popuptype=detailview&select=enable&form=EditView&form_submit=false')?>";

var intermediate_url="choose_template.php??variable_url="+url;

window.location=intermediate_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you what to echo out the full name of the current page: Use this to get it:

```
function curpage() {
    $pu = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pu .= "s";}
    $pu .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pu .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {$pu .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];}
    return $pu;
}

<?php echo "url = ".curpage(); ?>
```

This will alway work fine!